# Measurement Uncertainty of Correlated Quantities

Tags: laser, measurements, error-analysis

Using a Thorlabs S310C Detector with a calibration error of ±5%.

Let's say I do two measurements of laser power with this detector over a time period of 60s. The first measurement is bare input power, the second measurement is input power with a filter before. If I want to determine the absorption, I have to divide those two results. But how do the errors propagate?

Comment: Do you ask how to calculate the error, if we divide one quantity $x_1$ by a second quantity $x_2$ and both have different errors? So are you mainly interested in the propagation due to the functional relationship?

Answer (score 1):

If you have correlations between two measured quantities $A$ and $B$ then then the uncertainty in their ratio $f = A/B $ is
$$
\sigma_f^2 \approx f^2 \left[\left(\frac{\sigma_A}{A}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma_B}{B}\right)^2 - 2\frac{\sigma_{AB}}{AB} \right]
$$
where $\sigma^2_A$ and $\sigma^2_B$ are the variances in $A$ and $B$, respectively, and $\sigma_{AB}$ is the covariance of $A$ and $B$.  For a sample of $N$ measurements drawn from the underlying distribution, this can be estimated as
$$
\sigma_{AB} \sim \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i} (A_i - \bar{A})(B_i - \bar{B}).
$$

Several example rules for the propagation of uncertainty, including the effects of correlations, can be found on the [Wikipedia page on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty);  in fact, that's where I drew the first equation above from.